# restrict access on public folder in laravel 4.2

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

im fairly new to laravel and im currently working on a project that needs to store files in the server. What im doing is store it under `public/docs` the problem is the files under that directory is accessible all the time given that they know the url to the certain file. for example even if they are logged out if they know this url `http://localhost/dummy/public/uploads/docs/2016-06-02-10-52-43-oth-content-inventory-and-planning-spreadsheet.pdf` they would be able to access it what im thinking is to do something like this 
in my routes i would do something like

```
Route::any('uploads/docs/' , 'go to some controller to check if user can acces');
```

is this possible? thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's called public for a reason...

you should use storage instead (laravel 5) in storage you dont restrict access, actualy the opposite, you grant access to the file .

try this for laravel 4.2 (move the file after upload like this to a storage folder)

```
  Input::file('file')->move(__DIR__.'/storage/',Input::file('file')->getClientOriginalName());
  });
```

Anyway ,the conclusion is that you can't restrict access (you shouldn't even if there is a way) because it's meant to be public ! so you should use storage folder(or whatever its called in laravel 4)